# MySQL Query Caching

Tags: php, mysql, windows

I have a website, (running on windows server 2008 with mysql 5.5 and php 5.3) that will be going live soon, but the search part of the site is extremely slow if the query used has not already been cached. It effects the entire site when its working to search a large table with 125,000 rows.

What steps can I do to limit the performance impact on the website?

Comment: How long does the table search take? Is your database normalized?  Do you have indexes on the things you're searching?  What type of searches are these (e.g. FULLTEXT)?

Comment: Its a FULLTEXT index. See this question for the query causing the issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905963/optimize-select-query-with-order-by-and-match-against

Answer (score 0):

Mysql can handle lakhs of data and it doesn't slow down for mere 125 thousand rows unless you constructed a bad table structure and a bad query..

Here are some of the tips to fast up things,

1. Normalize your table structure
2. Have proper indexes
3. Try to write a simple query , you
   can check why your query runs slow
   by analysing the [slow query
   log.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html)
4. Try [explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) statement to know
   how mysql actually executes your
   query.
5. Even after this if the
       slowness persists and your requests
       to the mysql server are expected to
       huge then consider query caching
       techniques like [memcached](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php)
6. And last , what are the process that
   are running in your system. Too many
   process running and taking the
   memory could slow any other process
   running ...

Comment: Thanks. Can you have a look at this question to see if you notice anything that could be improved on. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905963/optimize-select-query-with-order-by-and-match-against